# C Memory Overflow (v2)

Tags: c, memory, allocation

**EDIT: Updated code with new Pastebin link but it's still stopping at the info->citizens[x]->name while loop. Added realloc to loops and tidied up the code. Any more comments would be greatly appreciated**

I'm having a few problems with memory allocation overflowing

http://pastebin.com/vukRGkq9 (v2)

No matter what I try, simply not enough memory is being allocated for info->citizens and gdb is often saying that it cannot access info->citizens[x]->name.

On occasion, I'll even get KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS errors directly after printf statements for strlen (Strlen is not used in the code at the point where gdb halts due to the error, but I'm assuming printf uses strlen in some way). I think it's something to do with how the structure is being allocated memory. So I was wondering if anyone could take a look?

Comment: Have you tried to shrink the code as much as possible so that only the problematic lines are present? It would be far easier to investigate, both for us and you.

Comment: What do you mean, "Updated code"? Do you mean you have made all the good answers to your question terrible answers because they now point to lines that are not there? Oh, yes, you do, the two versions are different enough to contain completely different sets of bugs. Ah well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't do `malloc(sizeof(PEOPLE*))`, because it allocates exactly amount of bytes for pointer (4 bytes on 32bit arch).
Seems the thing you want to do is `malloc(sizeof(PEOPLE) * N)` where N is the max. number of PEOPLE you want to put into that memory chunk.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the problem lies with:

```
info->citizens = malloc(sizeof(PEOPLE *));
info->citizens[0] = malloc(sizeof(PEOPLE *));
info->citizens[1] = malloc(sizeof(PEOPLE *));
```

Think about it logically what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I disagree, it's perfectly valid thing to give a hint instead of full answer, especially if question is (subjectively) trivial :)

Answer (score 1):

Your structs should almost certainly not contains members such as:

```
time_t *modtimes;
mode_t *modes;
bool *exists;
```

Instead you should simply use:

```
time_t modtimes;
mode_t modes;
bool exists;
```

In that way you do not need to dynamically allocate them, or subsequently release them.  The reasons are that a) they're small and b) their size is known in advance.  You *would* use:

```
char *name;
```

for a string field because it's not small and you don't know in advance how large it is.

Elsewhere in the code, you have the folllowing:

```
if(top)
{
  PEOPLE *info;
  info = malloc(sizeof(PEOPLE *));
}
```

If *top* is true then this code allocates a pointer and then immediately leaks it -- the scope of the second *info* is limited to the if statement so you can neither use it later nor can you release it later.  You would need to do something like this:

```
PEOPLE *process(PEOPLE *info, ...)
{
  if (top)
  {
    info = malloc(sizeof(PEOPLE));
  }

  info->name = strdup("Henry James");
  info->exists = true;
  return info;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have one too many levels of indirection. Why are you using `**citizens` instead of *?

Also, apart from the fact that you are allocating the space for a pointer, not the struct, there are a couple of weird things, such as the local variable `info` on line 31 means the initial allocation is out of scope once the block closes at line 34.

You need to think more clearly about what data is where.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of memory allocation issues with this code.  Those mentioned above plus numerous others, for example:

```
info->citizens[masterX]->name = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(dp->d_name)+1);
info->citizens[masterX]->name = dp->d_name;
```

You cannot copy strings in C through assignment (using =).  You can write this as:

```
info->citizens[masterX]->name = malloc(strlen(dp->d_name)+1);
strcpy(info->citizens[masterX]->name, dp->d_name);
```

Or you could condense the whole allocate & copy as follows:

```
info->citizens[masterX]->name = strdup(dp->d_name);
```

Similarly at lines 143/147 (except in that case you have also allocated one byte too few in your malloc call).